# "struct has no member named" error with gcc on dev machine

Tags: gcc, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ReadMethods.h"


int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{

DPDA WordChecker;
DPDA * WordCheckerPointer=&WordChecker;

WordChecker.DPDAFilename=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
WordChecker.DPDAInputFilename=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
WordChecker.DPDAOutputFilename=(char*)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
strcpy( WordChecker.DPDAFilename,argv[1]);
strcpy( WordChecker.DPDAInputFilename,argv[2]);
strcpy( WordChecker.DPDAOutputFilename,argv[3]);

readDPDA(argv[1],WordCheckerPointer);
readInputLines(argv[2],WordCheckerPointer,argv[3]);

return 0;
}
```

This is my code that gives error from mallocs until last strcpy() ,total 6 lines.The error is "DPDA has no member named DPDAFilename" and same for other fields for every malloc and strcpy linesthat i work on.Here is the part of header file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct tagRule{
char *startingState;
char symbolToPop;
char expectedInput;
char *endingState;
char symbolToPush;
}Rule;

typedef struct tagStackDPDA{
char * arrayOfSymbols;
int stackElementCount;
char * currentState;
}stackDPDA;

typedef struct tagDPDA{
char * alphabet;
char * stackSymbols;
char ** states;
char *startingState;
char **finalStates;
int finalStatesAmount;
Rule * ruleList;
stackDPDA stackOfDPDA;
int sizeArray[4];//This array holds amount values of states,alphabet symbols,stack       symbols and transition rules
char *DPDAFilename;
char *DPDAInputFilename;
char *DPDAOutputFilename;
}DPDA;
```

The code works fine in codeblocks environment but in gcc (-Wall -ansi).Those filenames come from input text files yet i am not sure it can cause this error. 
Edit:By the way I am using this command line to compile;

```
gcc -Wall -ansi main.c ReadMethods.h -o WordChecker
```

Comment: I would want to look at the output of `gcc -E` to see what your structure has been transformed to. It will print out the preprocessed code that the compiler really sees.  This will show you what (if anything) has happened to your DPDA structure type. You don't normally compile a header on the GCC command line. The code in the question compiles cleanly for me under GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9 — at least, under `-std=c11` instead of `-ansi` (which is equivalent to `-std=c89` which does not allow `//` comments. Remove the `//` comment and it is clean under `-ansi` too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out,it was the problem that prevented me to compile

Comment: Please give credit to [WadimX](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2995760/wadimx) for his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20001359/15168) which pushed me down the right track -- and hence you down the right track too.

Answer (score 1):

May be if you compile in C mode, you have to use C-style comments in header?
/**/ instead of //

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Only obsolescent (senescent) compilers have issues with `//` comments (and GCC is not one of those compilers, assuming it is GCC 4.x).  The `//` comments have been standard for 14 years or so, now, since C99 was defined. With that said, the `-ansi` option on the GCC command line forces GCC into obsolescent mode (equivalent to `-std=c89`), and then `//` comments are not permitted.